# How to repeat a "for" loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops, repeat

I can't figure out how to repeat this program, so the user would be able to input another set of hours.

Do I need to change this to a "Do...While" statement?

I was thinking about adding in a "User-defined function" at the end, but my professor might not allow that, since we haven't gotten there yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const float initialVolume = 130.00;
const float decreaseRate = 0.13;
string name;
int counter = 0;

int main()
{
    int hours,i,j,k;
    float remainingVolume, halfVolume, zeroVolume;

    cout << "Enter hours to see how much caffeine "
         << "is left in your body, after you drank your coffee: ";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << endl;
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);

    remainingVolume = initialVolume;

    for (i = 0; i < hours; i++)
    {
        counter++;
        remainingVolume = remainingVolume - decreaseRate * remainingVolume;
        cout << "Hour " << setw(5) << counter << setw(15) << remainingVolume << "mg"<< endl;
    }

    for (j = 0, halfVolume = 130.00; halfVolume > 65.0000; j++)
    {
        counter++;
        halfVolume = halfVolume - decreaseRate * halfVolume;
    }

    for (k = 0, zeroVolume = 130.00; zeroVolume > 0.0001; k++)
    {
        counter++;
        zeroVolume = zeroVolume - decreaseRate * zeroVolume;
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "It will take " << j << " hours to get caffeine levels to 65mg. \n" << endl;
    cout << "It will take " << k << " hours to get caffeine levels to 0mg." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes? Seriously, that sounds like it would work... did you have a follow-up question? Also, where is the opening brace for `main()`?

Comment: If you want to repeat something, you typically put it in a loop. If you want to repeat a loop, then it's just the same, put it inside another loop.

Comment: `do ... while (...)` is an option, though I almost always favor `while (...) {...}`. Your idea to define a function is excellent thinking; too bad that doesn't get more emphasis a lot earlier in programming instruction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068198/how-to-read-a-multiple-line-input-from-command-line-in-c-or-c


You can use this link for the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach that terminates if there's an error reading (e.g. the user types a non-integer value or presses e.g. `^D` (Linux/UNIX) or `^Z` (Windows) to generate an End-Of-File condition:

```
int main()
{
    int hours,i,j,k;
    float remainingVolume, halfVolume, zeroVolume;

    while (cout << "Enter hours to see how much caffeine "
                << "is left in your body, after you drank your coffee: " &&
           cin >> hours)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);
        ...etc...
    }
    // no need to return 0; - that's done implicitly
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This did solve my problem. But for some reason, my "hour" counter is off, when I type in another set of "hours".

<output>

Enter hours to see how much caffeine is left in your body, after you drank your coffee: 10

Hour   148       113.1000mg
Hour   149        98.3970mg
Hour   150        85.6054mg
Hour   151        74.4767mg
Hour   152        64.7947mg
Hour   153        56.3714mg
Hour   154        49.0431mg
Hour   155        42.6675mg
Hour   156        37.1207mg
Hour   157        32.2950mg

Comment: How would I be able to reset the counter back to 0?

Comment: @MatthewBarragan: ah yes - you'd set the counter back to 0 just inside the `while` loop.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest factoring the work to well-named functions an then basing the loop logic on how the user will terminate the loop.

Comment: Would you be able to give an example? That does sound like a logical POV, but being that I'm still a newbie, I'm not sure exactly how to execute this.